# How to attach and mount volumes to an EC2 instance using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I can't find a way to attach and mount volumes using cloudformation.

I can attach a volume using VolumeAttachment; however, when I do `lsblk` after my EC2 instance is in running state, I see this attached instances as being unmounted.

Is there a way to mount this instance from Cloudformation file?  I can mount this using linux commands but would be much better to handle everything from cloudformation instead.

Here is what I've so far:

```
"MyEc2Instance" : {
   "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
   "Properties" : {
      "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" }
   }
},
    "MyVolume" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Volume",
      "Properties" : {
        "Size" : "50",
        "AvailabilityZone" : "xyz"
      }
    },
    "attachment" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment",
      "Properties" : {
        "InstanceId" : { "Ref" : "MyEc2Instance" },
        "VolumeId"  : { "Ref" : "MyVolume" },
        "Device" : "/dev/sdh"
      }
    }
```

And when I do `lsblk` on the instance, this is the result i see:

```
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdh    202:112  0  50G  0 disk
```

Notice even though I specified device name to be 'sdh' it shows attached as 'xvdh'.  Why is that?  And as you can see this is unmounted.  How do I mount this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As mentioned by helloV you will need to mount it when the instance launches using UserData. I find the new YAML format for CloudFormation templates is much easier but I've put the example in JSON too.

JSON:

```
"UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
    "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
    "# create mount point directory\n",
    "mkdir /mnt/xvdh\n",
    "# create ext4 filesystem on new volume\n",    
    "mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdh\n",
    "# add an entry to fstab to mount volume during boot\n",
    "echo \"/dev/xvdh       /mnt/xvdh   ext4    defaults,nofail 0       2\" >> /etc/fstab\n",
    "# mount the volume on current boot\n",
    "mount -a\n"
]]}}
```

YAML:

```
UserData:
    'Fn::Base64': !Sub
      - |
        #!/bin/bash -xe
        # create mount point directory
        mkdir /mnt/xvdh
        # create ext4 filesystem on new volume           
        mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdh
        # add an entry to fstab to mount volume during boot
        echo "/dev/xvdh       /mnt/xvdh   ext4    defaults,nofail 0       2" >> /etc/fstab
        # mount the volume on current boot
        mount -a
```

Comment: I need to increase the root volume.  Will this work for root volume as well as this is creating a new file system?

Comment: @NHoI ok, this has helped me a ton. so thanks.  One question: will there be any issue if i mount an existing file system? instead of creating /mnt/xvdh what if i mount (just for example) /usr on this new disk.

Comment: No, as long as the existing file system has what you need under /usr. Be aware that the mount will hide everything under your mount, it will still exist so if you umount the original folder contents will return.

Comment: I found that there was a problem with updating fstab, so I used

"echo '/dev/xvdh /mnt/data ext4 defaults,nofail 0 2' | sudo tee --append /etc/fstab\n"

also a problem using the VolumeAttachment resource is that the volume is not actually attached until after instance creation, so the final mount execution does nothing.

Better to use the Volumes property of the Instance resource.

Answer (score 3):

Attaching a volume can be done at hypervisor level, hence you can attach a volume using CF.

But mounting a volume is at OS level and CF has no way of knowing/doing it. It is same as asking `How can I create a directory in cloudformation after launching an instance?`

How do you solve this problem? CF has EC2Instance property called [UserData](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-userdata). You supply the command to mount the attached volume. Here is one [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/deploying.applications.html#deployment-walkthrough-lamp-install)

```
{
   "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
   "Properties" : {
        ....
        "InstanceType"   : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" },
        "KeyName"        : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
        "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
             "#!/bin/bash -xe\n",
             "yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",

             "# Install the files and packages from the metadata\n",
             "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v ",
             "         --stack ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackName" },
             "         --resource WebServerInstance ",
             "         --configsets Install ",
             "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n"
        ]]}}
      }
    },
```